# is there a way to detect when the repeated items have finished loading in angular 1.0.8 stable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Between the ng-repeat div tags,

I've `div.cover_container.fetched` elements that display data fetched using `$http.get`

I want to attach event handlers on these elements, but I cannot do so because sometimes they've not finished loading.

The function responsible for attaching event handlers is `activateGear`

Even though I place the `activateGear` inside the success part, the `activateGear` does not always work because `div.cover_container.fetched` did not exist at the time the function is executed.

```
$http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      var items = data.stories;
      this.maxLimit = data.paging.count;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (this.items.length < this.maxLimit) {
          this.items.push(items[i]);
        }
      }
      activateGear();
```

the `activateGear` is the function that will attach the event handler on the repeated elements.

How do I achieve the above in angularjs 1.0.8?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to achieve the effect using `setInterval` as a workaround.

Hopefully I get what I wanted without such a workaround.

```
  MyWorks.prototype.nextPage = function() {
    if (this.busy) return;
    this.busy = true;
    var url = "/my_works?page=" + this.page + "&top=" + this.perPage + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
    $http.defaults.headers.get = { 'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' };
    $http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      var items = data.stories;
      this.maxLimit = data.paging.count;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (this.items.length < this.maxLimit) {
          this.items.push(items[i]);
        }
      }

      this.page = parseInt(this.items.length / this.perPage) + 1;

      var currentMyWorks = this;
      var theIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (currentMyWorks.busy == false) {
          activateGear();
          clearInterval(theIntervalId);
        }
      }, 300);
      this.busy = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is for you to separate concerns.

Turn your view into a directive where you can leverage the `link` function to operate on elements that have finished rendering.

`$http` is a provider you would use in a service, and therefore that's no place for DOM manipulation, same if you were trying to use it in a controller which is an even worse idea.

For angular directives docs read [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and a great learning resource: [egghead.io](http://egghead.io)

Comment: I am following this example. http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html and I also managed to get what I wanted using setInterval, so I am now interested on how to achieve the same thing without resorting to this workaround. See question updated

Comment: I would also be interested about separating the concerns as you have mentioned. But I'm not expert enough in angularjs to `turn view into a directive where i can leverage link function` I started angular less than a week ago.